# tableHeaderView doesn't display UIView properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add UIScrollView with paging as a header to my table, but unfortunately it is not displayed correctly.
The htableHaderView is resized to the size of my `imagesScrollView`, but only half of it is displayed the rest area is blank.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ImagesViewController *imagesScrollView = [[ImagesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImagesViewController" bundle:nil];


    tableView.tableHeaderView = imagesScrollView.view;
    imagesScrollView = nil;

}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code:

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ImagesViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ImagesViewController *imageVC  = [[ImagesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImagesViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:[imageVC view]];
    imageVC = nil;
}
@end
```

***ImagesViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ImagesViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *ViewInScrollView;
@end
```

***ImagesViewController.m***

```
#import "ImagesViewController.h"
@implementation ImagesViewController
@synthesize ScrollView;
@synthesize ViewInScrollView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self ViewInScrollView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768 * 2, 400)];
    [[self ViewInScrollView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [[self ScrollView] setContentSize:[[self ViewInScrollView] frame].size];
}
@end
```

`ImagesViewController`'s xib is a view, 768 wide by 200 tall (I made an iPad-based `UITableView` single-view application). Inside its `view` is a `UIScrollView`, set to take up the entire `[view frame]` area. Then I put a `UIView` inside of it.

My testing gives me a header that is an orange rectangle, and I can scroll it around as you would expect. This leads me to believe that maybe you need to check the shocks/struts of your `imagesScrollView` in Interface Builder. Make sure all of the margins and widths are fixed/flexible as you need for it to display properly.

Comment: It does for me. What have you tried? Did you replace the stock `UIView` in `ViewController`'s xib with a `UITableView`? If you do that, it should work. Can you give more information about how it's failing?